# My HTML button's javascript will not toggle second time

Tags: javascript, css, html, button, toggle

This is what I have so far:
**HTML:**

```
<button id="clockToggle" onclick="toggleClock()">Toggle Clock</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#clockWidget {
  display:none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function enableClock() {
  var clock = document.getElementById("clockWidget");
  clock.style.display="block";
}

function disableClock() {
  var clock = document.getElementById("clockWidget");
  clock.style.display="none";
}

function toggleClock() {
  var clock = document.getElementById("clockWidget");
  if(clock.style.display="none") {
    enableClock();
  }
  else {
    disableClock();
  }
}
```

**My goal is to make the button so that it will toggle the clockWidget on and off. If possible answer with JavaScript instead of jQuery.**
*P.S. If you vote my question down, at least comment on why you did so*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the if statement of your `toggleClock()` function you are missing a '=' and thus do not compare but instead set the display property of `clock`. This is why it only calls `enableClock()`. If you use the following it should work as expected:

```
if (clock.style.display == "none") {
    enableClock();
} else {
    disableClock();
}
```

Comment: And to avoid such mishaps, I suggest always use `===` and also have the constant value first `"none" === clock.style.display`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing another '=' in your comparison:

```
if(clock.style.display == "none") {
    enableClock();      
} else {
    disableClock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#clockToggle").click(function(){
  $("#clockWidget").toggle();
});
```